# Proving $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)}{3^{n^2-n}}=0$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n+1)}{3^{n^2-n}}=0$.
I prefer not to convert it to functions and use the L'hopital rule and without the taylor series.
I can't seem to think of a simple way which proves it. How should I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use comparison. For instance, for any $n\geq1$ we have $\ln(n+1)\leq n$ and $3^{n^2-n}\geq n^2$. This gives
$$
0\leq \frac{\ln(n+1)}{3^{n^2-n}}\leq \frac{n}{n^2}
$$
After a very simple limit calculation on the leftmost and rightmost expressions we conclude by the squeeze theorem that the middle expression must indeed converge to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using comparisons.

- $\ln(n+1)<n$
- $3^{n^2-n}>3^n>n^2$

Therefore $\frac{\ln(n+1)}{3^{n^2-n}}<\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}\to0$.

Comment: The second point isn't entirely true for $n=1$ or $2$. You get $1>3>1$ and $9>9>4$.

Comment: @Arthur As I'm sure you know, in such discussions, it is acceptable to leave off "for sufficiently large $n$".

Comment: No, I don't know that. I don't think it is.

Comment: @Arthur In the context of a limit to infinity, it is irrelevant what happens to the first few terms.

Comment: That I agree with fully. What I don't agree with is stating those inequalities unqualified. Regardless of what implicit context you might think other people understand.